# Adding Textbox and MessageBox to a class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a DLL for an existing project. The existing project is an application that calculates interest rates and is a Windows Form.

The code I've been given to create the DLL includes references to a TextBox and a MessageBox.

Here's a sample method in that code:

```
public static bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox.Tag + " is a required field.", Title);
        textBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've never created a class library/dll before, so I followed [the instructions here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/dll12222005064058am/dll.aspx).

When I build the solution (for the class library), I get the error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'TextBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   J:\LoanApplication\ValidatorSolution\ValidatorSolution\Class1.cs    24  38  ValidatorSolution

And I get it; I understand what the error is saying. My problem is that I don't know how to get around it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference System.Windows.Forms(use [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)) and include a using statement

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

For each external type you're using in your library, you need to help VS determine where it is and which one you mean.

Answer (score 3):

in your project , right click on "References", then click on "Add References" .
Now, in References manager window, just choose

```
System.Windows.Forms
```

click ok button and come back to your code page.

as usual you can now add System.Windows.Forms by using keyword:

```
using  System.Windows.Forms;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole error message and then add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` to your project and add `using System.Windows.Forms;` to the beginning of your source code.